# Como sumir com o NaN quando eu apagar o campo i8

Tags: javascript, nan

Eu tenho um formulário com dois campos `i8` e `i9` e uma função `calcular` que coloca os resultados num campo `result`. Quando o campo `i8` está em branco e a função `calcular()` é chamada, aparece escrito nele `NaN`. Como eu faço para resolver isso?

Eis o meu código:

```
<script>
String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
};
function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
//var money = id( el ).value ? id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' ) : 0; valor sem o R$NaN
var money = id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' );
return parseFloat( money )*1000;
}
function calcular()
{
    var total = getMoney('i9')-getMoney('i8');
    //id('result').value = 'R$'+ String(total/1000).formatMoney();
    id('result').value = String(total/1000).formatMoney();
}

</script>

<input id="result">
```

Comment: Acrescentei a descrição do seu problema à sua pergunta. Isso é muito importante, pois um monte de código sem maiores explicações tende a deixar usuários confusos e os leva a negativarem a sua pergunta. Neste site, é importante sempre se esforçar em redigir a pergunta de forma clara e descrever bem o problema que você está enfrentando para evitar esse tipo de coisa chata. De qualquer forma, por ora isso está resolvido. Seja bem-vindo ao site. :)

Answer (score 2):

O truque é usar a função [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Além disso, na função `getMoney(el)`, você multiplica por 1000 para depois ele dividir por 1000 na `calcular()`. Isso me parece ser uma gambiarra totalmente desnecessária, e por isso eu tirei.

Eis o seu código resultante. Para testar, clique no **primeiro** botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> lá em baixo:

```js
function formatMoney(value) {
    var negativo = value < 0;
    var v = Math.floor(Math.abs(value) * 100);
    var r = String(v);
    var s = r.length;
    r = s === 1 ? "0,0" + r
            : s === 2 ? "0," + r
            : r.substring(0, s - 2) + "," + r.substring(s - 2, s);
    for (var i = s - 5; i > 0; i -= 3) {
        r = r.substring(0, i) + "." + r.substring(i, r.length);
    }
    return (negativo ? "-" : "") + r;
};

function id(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function getMoney(el) {
    var money = parseFloat(id(el).value.replace(',', '.'));
    return isNaN(money) ? 0.0 : money;
}

function calcular() {
    var total = getMoney('i9') - getMoney('i8');
    id('result').value = formatMoney(total);
}
```

```html
<p>i8: <input type="text" id="i8" /></p>
<p>i9: <input type="text" id="i9" /></p>
<p>Resultado: <input type="text" id="result" readonly /></p>
<input type="button" onclick="javascipt:calcular();" value="Calcular"/>
```

Você deve ter percebido que mudei completamente a sua função `formatMoney`. Que inclusive deixou de ser um método *mix-in* de `String` e passou a ser uma função normal. O motivo para isso é que o seu método `formatMoney` não funcionava para formatar adequadamente números maiores que 1 milhão ou com muitas casas decimais.

Eis um teste com o seu método `formatMoney` original, note na saída produzida os problemas (clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> que está lá em baixo, o segundo desta resposta):

```js
String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
};

document.write("0".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("5".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("10".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("987.65".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("987.6543".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("1000".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("1000.23".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("999999.99".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("1999999.99".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("999999999.99".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("-999999999.99".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("0.05".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("-0.05".formatMoney() + "<br>");
document.write("0.005".formatMoney() + "<br>");
```

Eis um teste da nova versão de `formatMoney` (clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> que está lá em baixo, o terceiro e último):

```js
function formatMoney(value) {
    var negativo = value < 0;
    var v = Math.floor(Math.abs(value) * 100);
    var r = String(v);
    var s = r.length;
    r = s === 1 ? "0,0" + r
            : s === 2 ? "0," + r
            : r.substring(0, s - 2) + "," + r.substring(s - 2, s);
    for (var i = s - 5; i > 0; i -= 3) {
        r = r.substring(0, i) + "." + r.substring(i, r.length);
    }
    return (negativo ? "-" : "") + r;
};

document.write(formatMoney(0) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(5) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(10) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(987.65) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(987.6543) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(1000) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(1000.23) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(999999.99) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(1999999.99) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(999999999.99) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(-999999999.99) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(0.05) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(-0.05) + "<br>");
document.write(formatMoney(0.005) + "<br>");
```